# SSIS send mail task failing after deployment

Tags: sql-server, ssis, smtp, smtp-auth, ssis-2016

I am working SQL Server 2016 and things are working in Visual Studio, but when I deployed my project to the Integration service catalog, SSIS send email task failed.

I am getting below mentioned error:

> Send Mail Task: Error: An error occurred with the following error message:
>
> Failure sending mail.
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions IPaddress:25

Not sure what is happening and why it is failing only after deployment. Send email tasks are working fine, when I execute from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not giving you a solution, but anyway:

Maybe your LAN's FW is blocking a connection from server but not from your development PC?

Comment: Both my dev and deployment server is same